# How to extract names from the resume in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract the person name for Resume. I am not getting the correct output. What i have done till now is.

```
import en_core_web_sm
import spacy
import pdfplumber
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
pdf = pdfplumber.open('C:/Person.pdf')
page = pdf.pages[0]
doc = nlp(page.extract_text())
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents if X.label_ == 'PERSON'])
```

and my output is :

```
[('Mohamme mohammed24@yahoo.com\n', 'PERSON'), ('Mangalore', 'PERSON'), ('Demo Design1', 'PERSON'), ('Demo Design2', 'PERSON'), ('Demo Design3', 'PERSON'), ('Java', 'PERSON')]
```

I tried many thing but not able to get the only names. it includes many things like skills, email etc.

How can i extract all the details from resume example skills, phone no, name, years of experience, email.

Answer (score 3):

**Using spacy to extract the first and last names**

We have first defined a pattern that we want to search in our text. Here, we have created a simple pattern based on the fact that the First Name and Last Name of a person is always a Proper Noun. Hence we have specified spacy that searches for a pattern such that two continuous words whose part of speech tag is equal to PROPN (Proper Noun).

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

# load pre-trained model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# initialize matcher with a vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

def extract_name(resume_text):
    nlp_text = nlp(resume_text)
    
    # First name and Last name are always Proper Nouns
    pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}]
    
    matcher.add('NAME', None, [pattern])
    
    matches = matcher(nlp_text)
    
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = nlp_text[start:end]
        return span.text
```

Comment: # initialize matcher with a vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

def extract_name(resume_text):
    nlp_text = nlp(resume_text)

    # First name and Last name are always Proper Nouns
    pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}]

    matcher.add('NAME', None, *pattern)

    matches = matcher(nlp_text)

    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = nlp_text[start:end]
        return span.text

pdf = pdfplumber.open('C:/ZuhairResume.pdf')
page = pdf.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
extract_name(text)  // Here i need to call a method is this correct.

Comment: Write code properly - I hardly understand your question. Also, you need to simply write the above code and call the "extract_name()" function to get the names from the resume.

Comment: I am getting error like ValueError: [E178] Invalid pattern. Expected list of dicts but got: {'POS': 'PROPN'}. Maybe you accidentally passed a single pattern to Matcher.add instead of a list of patterns? If you only want to add one pattern, make sure to wrap it in a list. For example: matcher.add('NAME', [pattern])

Comment: @sripandianman sounds good. I have edit the solution - if the solution helped you consider upvoting and selecting as the right answer.